# I have Modulus and Exponent how to generate JWE for some payload using JavaScript

Tags: jwt, rsa, jwe, jose, jose4j

We have a requirement where we will get modulus from service call to be used for encrypting (JWE) some data at client side

Example of modulus, and exponent (cannot be changed formats)

```
{
    "modulus": "27921539673885756361419156461021876226845445107119091471889357242434620975884246915491757578902818243635599516623468500514580405147004224500529164165175418080296534603814824585285975894063860621755306618118216921360279638839263914961253991832884140339596254323951288609833783395465326689135784495563016459486626252473786100255392919521063720839389818627863002071132030078117996952009416186398741189513852165509082498538217432301912889497439381201450665516807813007876250433333575497298297093128243716605741969339467610040987340399020751603712326128652340270376013354086995479489210853404012768884141354633100389617819",
    "exponent": "65537",
     
}
```

I am trying to use JavaScript Jose library to generate JWE, but no luck.

I am following below example from internet, but my question is modulus I am using seems to be in biginteger (i guess) format, but the example showing different format.

Is there a better way I can use JOSE for JWE if I have modulus and exponent as shown above? Or can it be done as its shown below, but I am getting an error:

```
var cryptographer = new Jose.WebCryptographer();
var rsa_key = Jose.Utils.importRsaPublicKey(
  {
    n:
      "c2:4b:af:0f:2d:2b:ad:36:72:a7:91:0f:ee:30:a0:95:d5:3a:46:82:86:96:7e:42:c6:fe:8f:20:97:af:49:f6:48:a3:91:53:ac:2e:e6:ec:9a:9a:e0:0a:fb:1c:db:44:40:5b:8c:fc:d5:1c:cb:b6:9b:60:c0:a8:ac:06:f1:6b:29:5e:2f:7b:09:d9:93:32:da:3f:db:53:9c:2e:ea:3b:41:7f:6b:c9:7b:88:9f:2e:c5:dd:42:1e:7f:8f:04:f6:60:3c:fe:43:6d:32:10:ce:8d:99:cb:76:f7:10:97:05:af:28:1e:39:0f:78:35:50:7b:8e:28:22:a4:7d:11:51:22:d1:0e:ab:6b:6f:96:cb:cf:7d:eb:c6:aa:a2:6a:2e:97:2a:93:af:a5:89:e6:c8:bc:9f:fd:85:2b:0f:b4:c0:e4:ca:b5:a7:9a:01:05:81:93:6b:f5:8d:1c:f7:f3:77:0e:6e:53:34:92:0f:48:21:34:33:44:14:5e:4a:00:41:3a:7d:cb:38:82:c1:65:e0:79:ea:a1:05:84:b2:6e:40:19:77:1a:0e:38:4b:28:1f:34:b5:cb:ac:c5:2f:58:51:d7:ec:a8:08:0e:7c:c0:20:c1:5e:a1:4d:b1:30:17:63:0e:e7:58:8e:7f:6e:9f:a4:77:8b:1e:a2:d2:2e:1b:e9",
    e: 65537
  },
  "RSA-OAEP"
);
var encrypter = new Jose.JoseJWE.Encrypter(cryptographer, rsa_key);
encrypter
  .encrypt("hello world")
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal string representing the modulus must be converted to a hexadecimal string with the proper formatting. In the following code this is done by the `convert` function.
The example encrypts and decrypts a plaintext and is essentially taken from the description of [js-jose](https://github.com/square/js-jose#example-encryption). The converted modulus is used for the encryption.
  The validity of the conversion can be cross checked e.g. [here](https://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php) (and can of course also be concluded from the successful decryption):

```js
function convert(modulus){
    var nHex = BigInt(modulus).toString(16);                           // Convert from dec to hex
    var nHexPadded = nHex.length % 2 ? "0" + nHex : nHex;              // Pad if necessary with a leading 0
    var nHexPaddedFormatted = nHexPadded.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(':');   // Separate each byte with a :
    return nHexPaddedFormatted;
}

var exponent = "65537";
var modulus = "24527552248658638593238312534622665239452237617916915035327410973877933321625015819725141075075211032977064656616272935088402961419107720169032602127557052115192166251022433499097931189631750439635561603835889998309453723345666313950232348492443075827282756304618422730925476259619200114387693134398859680038905017069367126679713008966792133309640987499113594495057801427098321936394744165577110835460409347737585308896989425915113198172049505101019813693205226199749749144689080410566381237890461144281136847243342701604504885554436502186579457750948522590884398208445448252725393629705457022749423572745479491820521";
console.log(convert(modulus).replace(/(.{60})/g,'$1\n'));
     
var publicKey = Jose.Utils.importRsaPublicKey(
    {
        /*
        n: "c2:4b:af:0f:2d:2b:ad:36:72:a7:91:0f:ee:30:a0:95:d5:3a:46:82:86:96:7e:42:c6:fe:8f:20:97:af:49:f6:48:a3:91:53:ac:2e:e6:ec:9a:9a:e0:0a:fb:1c:db:44:40:5b:8c:fc:d5:1c:cb:b6:9b:60:c0:a8:ac:06:f1:6b:29:5e:2f:7b:09:d9:93:32:da:3f:db:53:9c:2e:ea:3b:41:7f:6b:c9:7b:88:9f:2e:c5:dd:42:1e:7f:8f:04:f6:60:3c:fe:43:6d:32:10:ce:8d:99:cb:76:f7:10:97:05:af:28:1e:39:0f:78:35:50:7b:8e:28:22:a4:7d:11:51:22:d1:0e:ab:6b:6f:96:cb:cf:7d:eb:c6:aa:a2:6a:2e:97:2a:93:af:a5:89:e6:c8:bc:9f:fd:85:2b:0f:b4:c0:e4:ca:b5:a7:9a:01:05:81:93:6b:f5:8d:1c:f7:f3:77:0e:6e:53:34:92:0f:48:21:34:33:44:14:5e:4a:00:41:3a:7d:cb:38:82:c1:65:e0:79:ea:a1:05:84:b2:6e:40:19:77:1a:0e:38:4b:28:1f:34:b5:cb:ac:c5:2f:58:51:d7:ec:a8:08:0e:7c:c0:20:c1:5e:a1:4d:b1:30:17:63:0e:e7:58:8e:7f:6e:9f:a4:77:8b:1e:a2:d2:2e:1b:e9",
        */
        n: convert(modulus), // Apply the converted modulus                               
        e: parseInt(exponent)
    },
    "RSA-OAEP"
);

var privateKey = Jose.Utils.importRsaPrivateKey(
    {
        n:
        "00:c2:4b:af:0f:2d:2b:ad:36:72:a7:91:0f:ee:30:a0:95:d5:3a:46:82:86:96:7e:42:c6:fe:8f:20:97:af:49:f6:48:a3:91:53:ac:2e:e6:ec:9a:9a:e0:0a:fb:1c:db:44:40:5b:8c:fc:d5:1c:cb:b6:9b:60:c0:a8:ac:06:f1:6b:29:5e:2f:7b:09:d9:93:32:da:3f:db:53:9c:2e:ea:3b:41:7f:6b:c9:7b:88:9f:2e:c5:dd:42:1e:7f:8f:04:f6:60:3c:fe:43:6d:32:10:ce:8d:99:cb:76:f7:10:97:05:af:28:1e:39:0f:78:35:50:7b:8e:28:22:a4:7d:11:51:22:d1:0e:ab:6b:6f:96:cb:cf:7d:eb:c6:aa:a2:6a:2e:97:2a:93:af:a5:89:e6:c8:bc:9f:fd:85:2b:0f:b4:c0:e4:ca:b5:a7:9a:01:05:81:93:6b:f5:8d:1c:f7:f3:77:0e:6e:53:34:92:0f:48:21:34:33:44:14:5e:4a:00:41:3a:7d:cb:38:82:c1:65:e0:79:ea:a1:05:84:b2:6e:40:19:77:1a:0e:38:4b:28:1f:34:b5:cb:ac:c5:2f:58:51:d7:ec:a8:08:0e:7c:c0:20:c1:5e:a1:4d:b1:30:17:63:0e:e7:58:8e:7f:6e:9f:a4:77:8b:1e:a2:d2:2e:1b:e9",
        e: 65537,
        d:
        "37:b6:4b:f4:26:17:a8:0b:3c:c5:1f:ab:59:b9:47:d2:ae:d9:8e:ee:4e:79:48:ab:0d:34:61:06:0f:78:8b:d4:ba:ef:6b:f4:7a:22:d8:c4:6f:70:89:5d:9c:b3:a1:8b:e8:88:57:dd:07:9e:c2:2b:12:52:a3:eb:b9:a8:24:01:7e:53:2b:7a:34:50:d7:0c:75:d8:69:a3:87:dd:4b:fc:c1:c3:2f:bd:0e:57:16:8d:ea:de:8e:de:ff:e4:9a:9f:aa:e8:d2:5f:b3:27:ef:f9:ca:50:97:2e:fd:99:1c:34:dd:0c:bb:dd:d0:b9:bf:4f:dc:9d:de:94:50:66:2c:58:7e:c2:31:8b:41:56:49:6a:e6:11:14:53:a1:45:0d:15:8b:26:79:0f:c9:dc:ac:dc:c7:bc:55:2c:96:ed:a7:29:09:04:ee:00:74:60:e1:bc:97:7b:0a:b6:f2:83:82:79:65:e0:aa:88:9f:90:b0:0d:76:4d:3c:08:7e:a5:05:19:d4:8b:54:d3:f1:c1:a3:e3:a5:1e:aa:d6:c4:94:ad:6c:b3:8f:85:06:8a:6f:52:f8:a3:c3:e0:8d:67:35:2f:d4:18:fc:70:f4:71:bf:18:88:d6:a7:b7:04:8e:d3:06:ca:83:c3:2d:21:98:65:c9:41:2c:77:bf:4c:7c:8c:2c:01",      
        p:
        "00:fa:d6:06:46:5c:04:70:e6:ec:47:02:96:02:a5:e2:41:9d:bd:7b:97:28:a4:c5:3b:b5:9b:0a:6b:7d:b6:44:8a:28:1e:d1:ef:cb:44:ef:eb:4d:08:74:80:f5:cf:3b:b7:40:10:60:c9:18:1e:a5:76:4b:41:37:06:b2:71:03:60:25:77:db:d0:b2:21:dc:b0:32:90:a2:10:9a:d5:e6:e3:11:42:a1:9a:7a:26:3c:d3:12:56:db:25:07:69:be:ae:2c:b9:33:6c:29:e3:65:b9:5b:05:84:05:e6:da:c4:f4:3f:ab:84:60:6e:f0:5f:ba:a8:98:8f:72:2c:c8:40:d1",
        q:
        "00:c6:4b:ac:fe:40:1c:dc:6c:78:07:cc:3e:db:4e:d5:d0:17:3b:8f:04:f0:ae:c4:22:0d:8b:0a:4d:0f:9e:fe:c7:e6:38:b5:53:ba:a9:e8:f0:47:28:14:25:95:6a:79:ab:db:86:97:82:c5:1e:bd:80:a5:aa:a2:b7:a5:c7:48:17:c4:d9:c7:4f:50:2a:69:67:15:4c:0b:f5:e6:fb:20:23:5d:ea:ae:6c:c6:74:ba:cc:f8:06:2b:41:1f:b6:3f:2a:93:fa:f9:e1:ee:93:c3:92:ad:49:c7:8f:db:72:ff:6b:f0:f0:d6:2f:83:ce:1c:82:16:89:57:01:9f:49:2f:99",
        dp:
        "57:d4:c1:75:b9:9a:c4:7d:d7:96:35:cd:99:37:c4:b5:fd:29:f0:30:c9:c6:88:59:94:09:a9:e8:61:a8:84:ef:6b:84:ff:35:dc:13:53:7f:2d:06:1c:e5:5b:2d:29:57:cd:52:ee:d0:fb:65:1f:c3:00:2e:e1:b9:b2:99:e7:f8:ae:a5:fd:8e:62:11:81:59:21:1b:8b:e4:0c:93:81:b9:58:bd:e0:20:5b:4d:30:57:28:40:c9:93:79:b9:09:4f:ab:d1:5d:b4:2e:26:b5:e3:e5:7f:54:ef:4c:1a:a6:84:70:16:fa:cf:59:89:49:bb:ee:75:1d:25:79:90:d5:41",
        dq:
        "00:ab:eb:a8:8c:b7:21:4e:aa:6c:56:b6:6a:38:d1:dc:e6:91:7d:fd:bd:96:be:af:25:a7:00:49:6a:0e:85:16:f8:51:4e:11:48:0a:aa:8d:5e:e5:12:86:85:1f:4a:35:3b:1f:15:4d:fe:fe:d0:6c:14:41:8d:f3:8d:ad:99:5d:93:de:03:c2:9d:ad:2f:58:3b:1b:67:d7:66:d7:60:1a:b9:0f:10:0d:32:19:cd:d2:b7:2a:c2:8e:75:e3:fc:aa:3f:4c:15:68:d8:cd:74:27:37:e0:2d:fb:6b:6a:24:05:f7:9b:e9:f2:89:37:89:57:86:21:eb:e9:17:6a:f6:94:e1",
        qi:
        "0a:ed:5f:30:67:d5:e5:6e:4a:7a:35:49:fe:16:2f:1e:91:2b:39:c3:01:d3:d4:c0:4d:b3:fc:08:b0:66:e9:44:10:9e:5b:5a:ea:83:a5:9c:95:7a:58:70:35:28:e5:4d:ba:19:de:0d:66:f9:db:5c:f6:5b:24:27:9d:0b:2d:44:40:eb:33:3a:19:e2:1d:c0:b0:16:99:d1:c1:52:84:02:d6:67:06:32:f8:4d:cb:42:9f:7c:8a:e0:ad:df:40:6f:e4:8c:f6:f6:9e:1d:bd:43:e3:38:91:a2:d0:9e:60:ff:9d:8c:fb:72:5b:df:95:30:17:d2:f2:cb:7d:92:56:0a"
        },
        "RSA-OAEP"
    );

// Example based on https://github.com/square/js-jose#example-encryption
var cryptographer = new Jose.WebCryptographer();
var encrypter = new Jose.JoseJWE.Encrypter(cryptographer, publicKey);
encrypter
    .encrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
    .then(function(jwe) {
    
        console.log(jwe.replace(/(.{60})/g,'$1\n'));
        var decrypter = new Jose.JoseJWE.Decrypter(cryptographer, privateKey);
        decrypter
            .decrypt(jwe)
            .then(function(jwe_plain_text) {
            
                console.log(jwe_plain_text.replace(/(.{60})/g,'$1\n'));
            });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-jose/0.2.2/jose.min.js"></script>
```